# Error Handling in Microsoft PDW

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, parallel-data-warehouse

I am in the process of migrating certain stored procedures from SQL Server 2012 to Parallel Data Warehouse (working on Visual Studio 2013). I notice that several SQL Server built in commands are not supported in PDW, for example TRY...CATCH is not supported. Also RAISERROR for Exception Handling is also not supported. Could someone help me with an alternative here? In almost all the stored procedures that I need to migrate, TRY..CATCH exists.

Answer (score 1):

RAISERROR, TRY...CATCH, PRINT, @@Error_* functions were all added in the Microsoft Analytics Platform System v2 AU3 release. You can download the [Analytics Platform System Appliance Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=45294) documentation to learn more about the release.